# Application of discrete functional optimization in finding the optimal algorithm?

Tags: functional-analysis, discrete-mathematics, optimization

Discrete Hamiltonian method and variational calculus can be found in economics optimization, whereas each consumption path is considered a function from time to numbers, budgets are constrained and discounted sum of utilities are the functional which we want to maximize. I am wondering if there is any similar application of functional optimization in software design, where consumption can be think of as different logic, loops, etc., whereas objective be complexity, computational time, robustness, etc., and hardware, etc. as constraints? In such a discretized world in computer science we might not be able to differentiate anything but similar procedures might still be able to carry out?